# Can a company's IT Department see the downloads of its clients?

Tags: networking

If you are sitting in the IT department, is it possible to view or see the downloads (ex. mp3, video, pictures off Google) of a client, for example, of an employee in another department (same building)?

Is it possible to set the limit of downloads that a client can use?

Comment: If your company uses a proxy, yes...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

By using a [proxy server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server), all web traffic inbound and outbound will go via this server and can be logged, cached, copied.. whatever your admin wants.

By the same measures, blocking of certain file types is very possible.

Where I work, we have a Forefront Microsoft TMG Server as our Proxy server and I have MP3, MP4, AVI, EXE, ZIP, BAT, VBS and a whole heap of other extensions blocked for most users as well as logging on some other extensions.

We also have a blacklisted group of websites which we block and we log all web traffic for legal and HR/management purposes.

On top of this, we can also block by protocol (disallow torrent or FTP), limit bandwidth (call centre staff may only get 200kbps throughput), monitor bandwidth usage per user) - there are loads of possibilities.

Comment: Lets say you allowed torrents, now, some Linux distros use torrents as its downloading method. If a client downloaded a linux distro through torrents, could you see the ISO he/she downloaded, or just the size of the download on your web traffic?

Comment: Its dependant on how good your proxy is.  With mine, no - but if I saw someone torrenting, I could capture copies of all data going into/out of that machine and run it through a packet inspector (such as Wireshark) and then I would be able to see the ISO

Comment: What Fazer87 didn't say explicitly is that because he is using a proxy server, he is also able to look at secure encrypted http connections ( more then likely ), and prevent those file extensions and websites even over a secure encrypted connection.  There are also other ways to do that beyond just the proxy server.

Comment: Normally yes - but TMG is notorious for falling over when trying

Comment: Wouldn't this fail if an end-user uses a vpn (ie if the communication is encrypted)? The only thing you see in that case would be the encrypted traffic going to the vpn server.

Comment: Not necessarily - most corporate firewalls or proxies will block VPN to an external location - making this a null issue and an impossibility

Answer (score 1):

It depends the network gears your IT Network team uses, but technically it is possible, and generally done in most large companies.

For instance, the use of a proxy server allows your IT department to control the internet access. They are able to set which site you can't browse, which file extension you can't download, and even set the bandwidth usage limit per user/site/category/etc...

Such a tool also provides reporting functionality, so they can produce reports on the bandwidth usage, top visited sites,... even per user.

Hope this helps.